# What is the default charset for MySQL varbinary string interpretaion?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, varbinary

Sometimes I would use `varbinary` instead of `varchar`, especially when I need trailing white-spaces to count during `=` comparison and am not interested in using the `LIKE` operator for this purpose.

When selecting, I can specify which charset to use when decoding like so:
`select convert(myvarbinary using utf8) from mytable`

But most times, I just `select myvarbinary from mytable` and it works just fine.

My question is, in the latter, when I do not specify the charset, what is the default character set coming from? On varchar, it is actually set on a per table or even a per-column basis, but not so for varbinary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VARBINARY` has no `CHARACTER SET`.  All comparisons are done bit-by-bit.  Such comparisons are somewhat like `COLLATE ..._bin`.

For *most* applications it is best to do everything in `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

The only reason I can think of for `convert(myvarbinary using utf8)` is if you have various encodings in a single column.  *That* sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: Yea, that would be a nightmare. I don't see how this answers my question though. I'm asking, if I do not run `convert` when selecting from `myvarbinary`, then what charset does it use to render the otherwise binary data? I assume this is either a session or database default, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Let's get some more info on the plate...  Wny are you using `VARBINARY`?  What does the `SELECT` (or other query) look like?  What are you comparing the `VARBINARY` to?  If the other side of the '=' (etc) is also `VARBINARY`, then nothing needs to be "converted".  There is also an issue of "coercible".  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html (etc).

Comment: The main reason I would use `varbinary` for character data is because this way the `=` clause checks trailing spaces and case sensitivity by default. I also like that the index length is byte for byte instead of 3 bytes per character like a `varchar utf8`. (I know I can use `latin1`. Also I admit I don't fully understand index length)

Comment: The other side of `=` might be a Base-64 representation of a hash for example, supplied by the application as a string. So no, this is not comparing two varbinaries together within MySQL.

Comment: When I select the data, particularly using the command line `mysql` tool, it is rendered as text just like a `varchar` column would be. When I select using an application connector it depends on whether I request a string or byte array, so I guess I should limit this question to the command line `mysql` tool. The question being which charset it uses to render a `varbinary` column.

Comment: `SELECT`, whether through commandline mysql or through connector, converts `VARCHAR` fields according to `character_set_result`.  For `VARBINARY`, there is no conversion; the bits are blindly sent to the client.  Numeric values (`INT`, etc) and `ENUMs` and `DATEs` are converted to strings during the transmission.